# How can I send a request to an HTML file on my PC as if it were a real server using Python/Requests?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, server, request

I've been trying making websites recently and I am trying to make a python code to check some vulnerabilities and bugs that might occur on the website.

Issue is that I currently don't have a domain and can't test it with a real server so I was wondering, in the meantime, if I could send "requests" to the index.html file as if it were a real server somehow.

[image: Here is an image of what my directory looks like]

Anything would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a real web server on your pc.  Using Flask, docker, etc.

Then just point your python tests at that new web server.

Comment: Thanks. But how could I do this?

Comment: I would take a look at this: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application